# Adding const objects

Tags: c++

I have a custom class. Let's call it apple. I overload the addition operator as so:

```
apple apple::operator+(const apple & other)
{
    return apple
    (
        this->x + other.x,
        this->y + other.y,
        this->z + other.z
    );
}
```

and it works great... until i try adding two const apples.

```
const apple apple1;
const apple apple2;

auto apple3 = apple1 + apple2;
```

gives me an error 'no operator "+" matches these operands
            operand types are: const apple  + const apple'

Is there some trick to adding const objects?

Answer (score 6):

You need to mark the addition operator itself as `const`:

```
apple apple::operator+(const apple & other) const;
```

The current form of the operator does not guarantee that `this` will not be mutated (even though it does not actually mutate it), so when the LHS of the addition is a `const apple` the compiler cannot use it and complains that no suitable operator is available.

Note that the usual practice is to implement custom addition by defining a free function `operator+` instead of a member, because this way the compiler can use constructors to convert  the LHS of the addition to an `apple` if required -- this is not possible if `operator+` is a member function.